# How to check whether a target is exported or not in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Please see the below minimal example:

```
project(sample)

add_library(Foo foo.cpp foo.h)
add_library(Bar bar.cpp bar.h)

target_link_libraries(Bar Foo)

export(TARGETS Bar FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BarTargets.cmake")
```

This will result in error `export called with target "Bar" which requires target "Foo" that is not in any export set`

Is there a way to achieve something like the below?

```
project(sample)

add_library(Foo foo.cpp foo.h)
add_library(Bar bar.cpp bar.h)

target_link_libraries(Bar Foo)

# if(All Bar's dependent target is exported)
  export(TARGETS Bar FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BarTargets.cmake")
# endif()
```

Comment: Is your question really "_How to check whether a target is exported or not in CMake?_", or is it actually "How can I check in CMake whether a target export set is not missing any dependencies?"

Comment: @user yes it is, here's more context, we are providing a cmake function called `GenerateBar` for different teams to use, and one of the input to the `GenerateBar` function are the targets `Bar` will link to, some teams write proper CMake that exports their `Foo`s, but some teams unfortunately does not write proper CMake, so they don't export their `Foo`s. Without the `if`, teams that doesn't export their `Foo`s will see the error, and I am trying to avoid this error for them. The same problem also happens to `install(EXPORT)` as well, but let's try to solve `export` first.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any target or directory property for doing this. However the way you're trying to go here doesn't seem a good way of handling things: If you encounter such a cmake error message, then the following things could be wrong: 1) You exported the target by accident. (Solution: remove the export) 2) You need to rewrite the lib to remove the dependency 3) The the dependency wasn't supported by accident (Solution: export dependency) Note that for none of those scenarios ignoring the error results in the appropriate state of the project...

Comment: If your `GenerateBar` functionality is used exclusively though, You could introduce global properties storing whether the export happened via your cmake function. However as already stated imho you **should** get a fatal error here as "ignoring the issue until the other team has fixed their part of the project" is basically just the equivalent of sweeping the problem under the rug and it will result in problems later, possibly at a time when you're already struggling to meet a deadline...